# Why can't I take value from my form? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to pass data from form into JavaScript variables but I am having an issue, Errors are listed below.

```
<div>
  <form>
    <select id="month" name="month"> 
      <option value="11">11</option>
    </select>
  </form>
</div>

<button onclick="calculate()"></button>

<script>
  function calculate() {
    var countMonth = document.getElementById(month).value;
    alert(countMonth);
  }
```

> Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
>    at calculate (DateTracker.html:81)   at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Comment: JScript would refer to Microsoft's https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript.  I assume that's not what you meant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to quote strings:
`document.getElementById('month')`
What you have will try to retrieve variable `month`, which should be your select DOM element.

Comment: Sorry SO didn't let me reply prevously, thank you for pointing out the error!